# Dynamic Image for Facebook Opengraph og:image meta tag

Tags: dynamic, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to share an image from my website on facebook. The image can be dynamic, but other meta will remain the same.

Is there a way I can have dynamic data in OG:IMAGE tag, or will I have to go with the other option of FB Post APIs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes and no. Facebook scrapes your site once, and cached the metadata that it finds, unless you specifically go [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and force the scraper to crawl your site again. The cache does generally expire (perhaps after 1-2 days?), so when requested again outside of this cache period, Facebook will crawl the site again.

You can have a dynamically generated `og:image` meta tag, but it will only be read the **one** time (per cache period), and only that instance of the image will be saved.

For example, if user A shares your page, and your page returns `imageA.png` in the `og:image` tag, then that is the image that will be associated with your page's metadata.

If user B then shares the *same page* within the *same cache period*, Facebook will forgo the metadata scraping and assume that `imageA.png` is still a valid `og:image`.

Comment: One option to make the dynamic og:image dynamic show on Facebook is to add a cachebuster to the og:image src. Therefore with every page rescraping from Facebook (every 24 hours) it will see a new image.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/sonpython/7327decca53f2b94d5bda14a31bb3492).

You should ping facebook to recrawl your page again every time you update your og:image tag.

```
def share_facebook_fanpage(link,msg,PAGE_ID,OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN,apiversion='v2.8'):
    BASE_URL = "https://graph.facebook.com/%s" % apiversion
    POST_URL = "%s/%s/feed" % (BASE_URL, PAGE_ID)

    # force facebook scape the link first to avoid not showing thumb
    f = requests.post(BASE_URL, data={
        'id': link,
        'scrape': True,
        'access_token': OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN
    })

    # share the link
    r = requests.post(POST_URL, data={'access_token': OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN, 'link': link, 'message':msg})
```