# How to develop site which dynamically changes og:image facebook property?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

Basically, I am making a website which has dynamic og:image property. I have added 100 images and changing the images by rand function in PHP.
The problem I am getting is that Facebook have cached my website and everytime user shares the URL, it shows the same image every time. I want Facebook to recrawl everytime the link is posted and shows random images.

Here is the code of the page I have developed:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <meta name="twitter:card" value="summary"> 

        <meta property="fb:app_id" content="xxxxxxxxxxxxx10" />
        <meta property="og:description" content="Like it? Share with friends... "/>
        <meta property="og:title" content="Your future company is" />
        <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
        <meta property="og:url" content="http://justtodo.xyz/company/" />
        <?php 
            $imageURL = 'http://justtodo.xyz/company/images/' . rand(1, 100) . '_260x135.jpg';
        ?>
        <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo($imageURL)?>"  />
        <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
        <meta property="og:image:width" content="200" />
        <meta property="og:image:height" content="200" />


    <script>
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

      ga('create', 'UA-100487432-1', 'auto');
      ga('send', 'pageview');

    </script>

    <script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"  integrity="sha256-iBcUE/x23aI6syuqF7EeT/+JFBxjPs5zeFJEXxumwb0="  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>




    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId            : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx10',
          autoLogAppEvents : true,
          xfbml            : true,
          version          : 'v2.9'
        });
        FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
      };

      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

        FB.api('https://graph.facebook.com/', 'post', {
            id: '<?php echo($imageURL)?>',
            scrape: true
        }, function(response) {
            //console.log('rescrape!',response);
        });
    </script>

    <title>Your future company...</title>


    <META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="0; URL=https://youtu.be/uqJNjb-zg3s">
    <script>
    setTimeout(function () {    
    window.location.href = "https://youtu.be/uqJNjb-zg3s"; 
    },10);
    </script>



    </head>
<body>


    <div style="text-align: center;font-size:2em;font-family:Consolas, Andale Mono, Lucida Console,Lucida Sans Typewriter, Monaco, Courier New, monospace">Loading your company...</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Share a unique URL instead of the same URL

Answer (score 0):

Do you only have 100 pictures? I already have over 500 and I also want to know how you do it. This "Facebook comments game" has already turned into a fever. Well, as far as I've researched, there are 3 ways to change the Facebook cache image.
1.) Every 24 hours Facebook searches for a new image automatically (this is not useful for us).
2.) Using https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ (I think we could do with the "extract again" button is in infinite loop, but I do not know how to do this and besides this only works while we have the site open in the browser).
3.) You can request the update with this AJAX code:

```
Var fbxhr = new XMLHttpRequest ();
fbxhr.open ("POST", "https://graph.facebook.com", true);
fbxhr.setRequestHeader ("Content-type", "application / x-www-form-urlencoded");
fbxhr.send ("id = http: //you_site.com/&scrape=true");
```

This JavaScript code plus this tag:

```
<Meta http-equiv = "refresh" content = "0"/>
```

And with this PHP code:

```
<Meta property = "og: image" content = "<? Php echo 'http://your_site.com/'.mt_rand(1,100).'.jpg';?>"/>
```

This causes the page to be updated every 0 seconds and receive a new random image that can be named from "1.jpg" to "100.jpg".
Then request via AJAX that the image be updated.
You can also do the loop inside the Javascript itself, but you would have to make PHP out to be called inside the loop. I just have not tested it yet.

My problem is: this only works while I have my site open in the browser giving infinite refresh.

Edit: The response of this post was on 06/03/2017 the same day that this game began to appear. Only I do not understand anything about Python. Can you tell me how to put Python in my HTML?

Link: [Dynamic Image for Facebook Opengraph og:image meta tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15832055/dynamic-image-for-facebook-opengraph-ogimage-meta-tag)